# Ввод в консоль код

Tags: javascript, консоль

Когда в консоль напишешь время в цифрах, он должен приветствовать исходя от заданного времени.
Например я введу цифру 17, ответ должен приветствовать "Добрый день!"
Или же введу 9, ответ: "Доброе утро!"

Как это сделать в самом консоль?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: о какой консоли речь?

Comment: Составить программу, которая выводит на экран различные приветствия в зависимости от введенного времени. в js.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function sayHello(time) {
  if (time >= 0 && time < 7) {
    console.log('Доброй ночи');
  } else if (time >= 7 && time < 20) {
    console.log('Добрый день');
  } else if (time >= 20 && time <= 24) {
    console.log('Добрый вечер');
  }
}

window.sayHello = sayHello;
```

Как вариант чтобы работать именно через консоль

Answer (score -2):

Мне кажется - я сужу по этому воросу и по закрытому вопросу "Составить программу", что проблема у автора вопроса не с js.

JS - это язык. программа, написанная на этом языке, должна *как то* исполняться.

Простых способов выполнить программу на js - два:

1. загрузить её в браузер
2. выполнить при помощи node.js

Возьмем для примера задачу автора, и рассмотрим её решение.

**Шаг 0.**

Это - функция, котрая на вход принимает ввод пользователя (и мы неявно предполагаем, что это число от 0 до 23 - число часов в текущем времени), а на выходе говорит приветствие, зависящее от времени.

```
        function sayHello(time) {
          if (time >= 6 && time < 12) {
            return('Доброе утро');
          } else if (time >= 12 && time < 18) {
            return('Добрый день');
          } else {
            return('Добрый вечер');
          }
        }
```

Эта функция реализует алгоритм, но как ввести в неё данные и как показать ответ, который она возвращает?

**Шаг 1. Запуск кода в браузере. Взаимодействие с пользователем через prompt() и alert().**

(Отметим, что функция prompt() имеет еще и версию с двумя параметрами: второй параметр - это значение по умолчанию в том случае, если пользователь ничего не ввел.)

Создадим такой файл:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="ru">
      <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            let time = prompt( 'какое у вас время (в часах)?' );

            if (time >= 6  && time < 12 ) {
               alert( 'Доброе утро' );
            } else if (time >=  12 && time < 18 ) {
               alert( 'Добрый день' );
            } else {
               alert( 'Добрый вечер' );
            }    

        </script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <h3>Учебное задание выполнено!</h3>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Сохраним этот файл на диске как test.html и откроем его в браузере.

[image: Выполнение кода в браузере]

Результат - мы можем взаимодействовать с программой при помощи подсказок, котрые появляются над пустой страницей. А когда подсказки кончились - на странице возникает надпись "учебное задание выполнено!".

Что происходит при загрузке этой страницы в браузер? Браузер начинает интерпретировать загруженную страницу, добирается до тега ,  интерпретирует скрипт и выполняет его. Скрипт выполняется до отображения основного текста страницы, а так как он прерывается функциями prompt() и alert() - текст отобразится уже после завершения программы.

**Шаг 2. Консоль браузера. отладка.**

Если нажать клавишу F12, то справа (по умолчанию) открывается консоль, которая позволяет, вообще говоря, делать много разного. Нас интересует сейчас так называаемая "печать в консоль".

[image: Консоль]

Изменим файл вот так:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="ru">
      <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            let time = prompt( 'какое у вас время (в часах)?' );

            if (time >= 6  && time < 12 ) {
               console.log( 'Доброе утро' );
            } else if (time >=  12 && time < 18 ) {
               console.log( 'Добрый день' );
            } else {
               console.log( 'Добрый вечер' );
            }    

        </script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <h3>Учебное задание выполнено!</h3>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Мы получим надпись из алгоритма не в виде всплывающего окна, а в виде надписи в поле "console" (не забудьте нажать F12 еще ДО ввода времени, чтобы увидеть, как эта надпись появится)

[image: печать в консоль]

И таким способом можно печатать из программы любые сообщения, например, значения переменных, что может понадобиться для отладки боее сложных алгоритмов.

**Шаг 3. В игру вступает нода (node.js)**
node.js - это "исполнитель" javascript, который умеет запускать js-файлы.
Чтобы не пересказывать весь "учебник", я просто сошлюсь на сайт https://javascript.ru/ , на его скринкаст https://learn.javascript.ru/screencast/nodejs где в первых двух уроках объясняется общая информация о том, что такое node.js, а третий урок как раз посвящен её установке. Будем считать, что нода у Вас уже установлена, и команда `node --version` возвращает что то типа `v14.17.6`.

Создадим файл со скриптом test.js

```
    const readline = require('readline').createInterface({
      input: process.stdin,
      output: process.stdout
    });

    readline.question('какое у вас время (в часах)?', time => {
      
            if (time >= 6  && time < 12 ) {
               console.log( 'Доброе утро' );
            } else if (time >=  12 && time < 18 ) {
               console.log( 'Добрый день' );
            } else {
               console.log( 'Добрый вечер' );
            }   

      readline.close();
    });
```

Тогда при его запуске командой `node test.js` Вы увидите:

[image: печать из ноды]

*Таким образом, у Вас есть способ запускать учебные js - скрипты.*
Конечно, мой ответ - это лишь маленькая часть знаний, но я надеюсь, что он будет полезен в случае, когда Вы в первый раз пытаетесь запустить js - скрипт.

Comment: Спасибо, буду очень рада!)

Comment: Например в С++ это выглядит так: int main()
{
    int n = 1;
    
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Russian");
 
   do
    {
        cout << "Который час?:";
        cin >> n;
        switch (n) {
        case 4:
        case 5:
        case 6:
        case 7:
        case 8:
        case 9:
        case 10:
           cout << "Доброе утро!";
            break;
        case 11:
        case 12:
        case 13:
        case 14:
        case 15:
        case 16:
            cout << "Добрый день!";
            break;
        case 17:
     и т.д

Comment: Я написал ответ так, как, мне кажется, он будет полезен. К сожалению, сейчас мой ответ "заминусован". Но если автор вопроса будет не против "принять его" (зеленая галочка рядом с количестком голосов) - значит, я потратил время не впустую.